# Resize flash video player to fill the page

Tags: javascript, flash, dom, video

I have a flash video player in a div inside a webpage, I'm trying to create a button that will resize this div to fill the whole page and hide everything else behind it. Has anyone tried to do it?
Problems:
1. It causes the flash to reload and the  video to restart
2. In some cases a flash banner from the webpage overlays my video player no matter what z-index I give it.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/faq) - it makes embedding Flash and doing dynamic things with it like resizing a lot simpler.  Their docs also explain [how best to fill the whole browser window](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/faq), and there is a good [example here of dynamic resizing](http://theflashfoundry.com/blog/node/4).

> In some cases a flash banner from the
>   webpage overlays my video player no
>   matter what z-index I give it.

If possible, try setting wmode="opaque" on the banner, this will make it respect z-indexes and other styling.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the opaque solution if I can get control on it. Do you have an idea re my other question - why my resized flash is getting reloaded? this isn't happening in IE btw, only in Firefox and alike